# Polar form of Laplacian operator.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates, laplacian

> Prove
>   $$
> \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}\right)
> $$
>   for $u=f(x,y)$

Where should I start from? $u$ is a general function of $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}$$
Then use that $$r^2=x^2+y^2 \text{ and } x=r\cos\theta \text{ and } y=r\sin\theta$$ to conclude the following:

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial  x}=\cos \theta \text{ and } \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\sin\theta$$

$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial  x}=\frac{-\sin \theta}{r} \text{ and } \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}=\frac{\cos \theta}{r}$$

Just to make things clear, the above is done so by the following method:

$x=r\cos \theta $ and so $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos\theta$.

$y=r\sin\theta$ and so $\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\sin\theta.$

$\theta=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ and so $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\frac{\frac{-y}{x^2}}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{-\sin\theta}{r} $

$\theta=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ and so $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}=\frac{\frac{x}{x^2}}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\cos\theta}{r} $

$$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}=\bigg(\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{\sin\theta}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \bigg)\bigg(\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{\sin\theta}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \bigg) \\ =\cos\theta\bigg(\cos\theta\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\sin\theta}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r \partial \theta}\bigg) \ \ \ -\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\bigg(-\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\cos\theta\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial\theta \partial r}-\frac{\cos\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \theta^2}\bigg) $$

$$= \cos^2\theta \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{2\sin\theta \cos\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}-\frac{2 \sin\theta \cos\theta}{r}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial\theta \partial r}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial\theta^2}$$

Then a very similar calculation gives

$$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}= \sin^2\theta \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2}-\frac{2\sin\theta \cos\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\frac{2 \sin\theta \cos\theta}{r}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial\theta \partial r}+\frac{\cos^2\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\cos^2\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial\theta^2}$$

Adding these two we then get,

$$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \theta ^2} $$

Comment: I understand all of the above but what do I do with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}cos\theta+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{-sin\theta}{r})$

Comment: @gbox I've made a change to my answer now. Sorry, it took a while to type up!

Comment: Some people who aren't used to operators might be confused by the very first two equations. It's a bit sloppy in my opinion. If you start calculating it for yourself, just replace each $\partial/ \partial r$ with $\partial u / \partial r$ and each $\partial / \partial \theta$ with $\partial u / \partial \theta$. At the end, you just get rid of $u$ and you got the Laplacian operator in polar coordinates for functions of the type $u(x(r,\theta), y(r,\theta)$. Keep in mind: If you "transform" a operator, just use an auxiliary function and "remove" it after you are done.

Answer (score 1):

To make things clear..  $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, not of $r$ and $\theta$. When we look at $u$ as a function of $r$ and $\theta$, we are abusing notation and looking at another function $\widetilde{u}$ defined by $$\widetilde{u}(r,\theta) =u(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta).$$ The left-hand side of the equality you want to prove is the laplacian of $u$ (in $x$ and $y$), and the right-hand side is the laplacian of $\widetilde{u}$ (in $r$ and $\theta $). Once you understand this, the computation boils down to not panicking and just using the chain rule repeatedly.