# confusion about the laplacian in polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a confusion about the following. If we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^2$ and we want to calculate the laplacian of this function polar coordinates.

I don't understand what it means. Does it mean we need to calculate :

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\frac{\partial f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)}{\partial x}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (\frac{\partial f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)}{\partial y})$$

Or does it mean we need to calculate :

$$\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) + \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2}(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$$

Moreover, I am really confused since I don't understand the fondamental difference between these two expressions.

Thank you !

Comment: A function $f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ does not have a partial derivative with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic interpretation is the second one. The Laplacian $\Delta f(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, which is defined as $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y)$, and expressing a function in polar coordinates just means substituting $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$. So first compute the second partials with respect to $x$ and $y$, then substitute.

However, the chain rule gives you **another way** of obtaining **the same result**, by performing a different sequence of operations. This involves first expressing $f$ in polar coordinates, and then taking partial derivatives of that expression with respect to $r$ and $\theta$. (Not with respect to $x$ and $y$ – that's sort of pointless, because if you wanted to do that, you should have done it directly on $f(x,y)$ instead of changing to polar coordinates to begin with.) How this works is explained in several other answers on this site, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/how-to-transform-a-laplacian-operator-from-x-y-coordinate-system-to-polar-syst) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695796/polar-form-of-laplacian-operator).

Comment: Thank you ! So it means that we have : $\Delta f(x,y) = \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x}(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y}(x,y)$, and this can be expressed in polar coordinates by substituing so we have : $\Delta f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x}(r \cos \theta,r \sin \theta) + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y}(r \cos \theta,r \sin \theta)$ which is the laplacian in polar coordinates. But an other way to expressed this laplacian in polar coordinates is :

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\frac{\partial f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)}{\partial r}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\frac{\partial f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)}{\partial \theta})$ which can be calculated using the chain rule.

Comment: @dghkgfzyukz: No, that's **not** the correct expression for the Laplacian in polar coordinates! See the questions that I linked to.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. Nothing is correct, or just my second comment ? I am going to look at the questions you linked.

Comment: @dghkgfzyukz: The first comment was OK, but the formula in the second comment was wrong.

Comment: Thanks to the link you provided I think I understand now, just need to do some calculations to see is evrything is effectively clear. Once again thank you for your patience and help.